# iOS App's Google Sign In functionality streamlining

Tags: ios, google-signin

I'm developing an app with a team - I am on the business end (not a coder). The app calls for sign-in with google functionality.

The team integrated this, but currently it requires that the user select his/her google login account, then **manually enter their password** if they're not already signed into their google account in the default browser.

This is a problem, as many google users (including myself) don't know my password by heart as its complex - it also requires the user exit the app which isn't ideal.  Is there a way to make this more streamlined?  I believe I have seen this with facebook logins where the user only needs to click 'accept' and they are returned to the app and logged in - no need for password.

Thanks for any input.

Bonus questions:

1. How did the browser know the user's existing login accounts?
2. This sign-in with google page is loading in the language of my current country rather than language of the user's google account.  Can this be changed?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, the user must be signed into the default browser in order to get the behavior you looking for. Once signed in, entering a password will no longer be needed unless the login is expired. I think this behavior is by design and is for security purposes.

Bonus questions:

1. Most probably it is using cache/cookies.
2. According to Google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/reference/Classes/GIDSignIn), seems like there is no way to change the language (but I might be wrong).